# Is 拒絶反応対受け入れ a grammatically correct way to say "acceptance versus rejection"?

Tags: grammar, translation

I am looking to translate "acceptance versus rejection" in the same sense as "acceptance versus alienation". Is the following statement grammatically correct? Does it make sense to word the following in Japanese?

> 拒絶反応対受け入れ

Comment: It's *grammatically* correct, but if you're talking about human relationships, "[拒絶]{きょぜつ}と[受容]{じゅよう}" might be better, at least in certain situations.

Answer (score 5):

When you say 「A [対]{たい} B」, the balance between the words on both sides of the 「対」 is of utmost importance.  Both word A and word B MUST have the same level of formality and phonetic impact.

Ideally speaking, the two words should be both Sino loanwords, both Japanese-origin words, or both katakana words.  Using this technique will help the Japanese reader/listener retain the phrase itself and the explanations more clearly.

Your phrase 「[拒絶反応]{きょぜつはんのう} 対 [受]{う}け[入]{い}れ」 has a problem in combining a sharp-sounding, on-reading word (拒絶反応) and a softer-sounding Yamatokotoba (受け入れ).  拒絶反応, naturally, sounds more formal than 受け入れ.  Native speakers of any language are very sensitive to these types of imbalances.

Your main concern seems to be whether or not your phrase is grammatical.  It is actually grammatical.  It is even difficult for a "A 対 B" structure to be ungrammatical.  All you need is two nouns if your only concern is grammar.

Finally, my actual word suggestions.  (You should have given us more context, a background story, etc. if I may be honest.)

拒絶、[疎外]{そがい}、[排除]{はいじょ} vs. [容認]{ようにん}、[受容]{じゅよう}、[了承]{りょうしょう}、[承諾]{しょうだく}

Again, as I stated, no one could recommend one word over the other without knowing what you are writing or speaking about.

Comment: Depending on the situation or context, 拒否反応{きょひはんおう} may also be relevant.